# Change text color on press

Tags: reactjs, react-native-web

I have a list of items that when i click, i display different content based on the value.
All works but for now im unable to change the color of the text of a selected item.
My text component:

```
const MediaSideText = ({ type, title, onTypeFilterChange }) => {
    const onMediaSectionClick = useCallback(() => {
        onTypeFilterChange(type);
    }, [type]);

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onMediaSectionClick}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                    <MediaIcon type={type} />
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
                <View style={styles.arrowContainer}>
                    <ArrowIcon style={(styles.expandableIcon, styles.expandedIcon)} />
                </View>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};
```

Panel Component:

````
<FlatList
                        key={options.value}
                        data={options}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => (
                            <MediaSideText
                                {...otherProps}
                                onTypeFilterChange={onTypeFilterChange}
                                style={styles.item}
                                type={item.value || ALL_MEDIA_TYPES}
                                title={item.label}
                            >
                                {item.value}
                            </MediaSideText>
                        )}
                    />
                </View>
    ```

And calling on the father:
````

````
const [mediaTypeFilter, setMediaTypeFilter] = useState(null);

const changeMediaTypeFilter = (data) => {
    setMediaTypeFilter(data);
};

<MediaSidePanel
                title={i18n.t('member-label:medias.sideBarTitle').toUpperCase()}
                typeValue={mediaTypeFilter}
                onTypeFilterChange={changeMediaTypeFilter}
            />
```
````

EDIT:

So i can change the color from my text, but when i click on another text, I want only the selected text to be red instead of clicking on 3 texts and 3 texts stay red.

```
const MediaSideText = ({ type, title, onTypeFilterChange }) => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

    const onMediaSectionClick = useCallback(() => {
        onTypeFilterChange(type);
        setSelected(true);
    }, [type]);
    const isSelected =
        selected === true ? { color: 'red' } : { color: 'rgb(180, 180, 180)' };
    console.log('isselec', isSelected);
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onMediaSectionClick}>
            <View style={[styles.container, isSelected]}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                    <MediaIcon type={type} />
                </View>
                <Text style={(styles.title, isSelected)}>{title}</Text>
                <View style={styles.arrowContainer}>
                    <ArrowIcon style={(styles.expandableIcon, styles.expandedIcon)} />
                </View>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};
```

Is there maybe anything i should do on the Flatlist ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have a color inside of state so you could change it when some action is done.

```js
const [color, setColor] = useState('white')

<h1 style={{color:color}}>hello</h1>
<button onClick={() => setColor('green')}>click</button>
```

Comment: can i n=make the setColor inside the callback onMediaSectionClick ?

Comment: Yes you can, const onMediaSectionClick = useCallback(() => {
        onTypeFilterChange(type);
setColor('green')
    }, [type]);